QGIS - catch return keypress on one qplaintextedit widget form
I'm certain this or similar has been asked here many times. I searched for it, but could not make the answers work.
During editing, I use a form which primary aim is to reduce mouse interaction during edit.
A attribute value can be modified (using a QPlainTextEdit widget)
Now, after updating the value, I need to click a button on the form to trigger an update-script.
It would be a real time-saver if, upon entering the value, the return keypress would trigger that update-script.
In other words: I need to catch the return keypress on that widget.
internet searches and searches here offer this answer. code-excerpt:
from qgis.PyQt import uic
frm = uic.loadUi( 'F_ChkPt.ui')

##  code snipped

def cmd_bt_chk():
    #update script 
    c_layer = frm.bt_active.text()
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName( c_layer )[0]
    
    n_pt = int(frm.tb_pt.toPlainText())
    
    feature = layer.getFeature( n_pt)
    feature[ c_VELDCHK] = '1'
    feature[ c_VELD] = frm.tb_Hg.toPlainText()
    layer.updateFeature(feature)
    cmd_bt_next()
     
class CustomPlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            cmd_bt_chk()               # update script
        super().keyPressEvent(event)        
        
#----------------------------------------------------------------
frm.bt_prev.clicked.connect( cmd_bt_prev)
frm.bt_prev.setShortcut("b")
frm.bt_next.clicked.connect( cmd_bt_next)
frm.bt_next.setShortcut("n")
frm.bt_chk.clicked.connect( cmd_bt_chk)
frm.bt_chk.setShortcut("m")

frm.tb_Hg = CustomPlainTextEdit()         # << add the keypress to the widget ??

frm.bt_active.clicked.connect( cmd_bt_SetActiveLayer)

frm.show()

This does nothing & no error is raised
I do not understand what 'frm.tb_Hg = CustomPlainTextEdit()' is supposed to accomplish
Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Assuming frm is a QWidget or QMainWindow, you should add new Widgets to it using a layout and its 'addWidget'-Method
I tried your CustomPlainTextEdit and it works for me in the following example:
from qgis.utils import iface 

class CustomPlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            print('hi')
        super().keyPressEvent(event) 
        
        
form = QMainWindow(iface.mainWindow())
central_widget = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
label = CustomPlainTextEdit()

form.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
layout.addWidget(label)

form.show()


Thanks, your code does indeed work.
The relevant part is, in fact, identical to mine.
Whereas yours creates a form and widget on the fly, I need to figure out how to make the code use a premade form (made in qtdesigner)
At least, I know the keypress part works, so progress :)

Your form instance should have some layouts as children. You can identify their name (LayoutName) in QtDesigner in the Object-Tree. In your code use frm.[any layoutname].addWidget(label) to add your custom Widget.
